# How can i receive a string from buffer array as UTF-8 (java to javascript)?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

i am trying to convert a small piece of code into javascript, everything is going well except for this part

```
new String(encode, Charsets.UTF_8);
```

I suppose this is creating a string from encoded hash, what i have in javascript is

```
const encoderUTF8 = new TextEncoder('utf-8');
const utf8 = new Uint8Array(encode.length);

const encoded = encoderUTF8.encodeInto(encode, utf8);
```

When i run it i get an error that says `The "src" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Buffer` .
The `encode` variable is a strange hash looking like this `dD${��d�N��t�\���P�` which is generated like so

```
const encode = Buffer.from(hash, 'base64');
```

Can someone please help me get this part together?
All I need is to figure out that `new String` part.

Comment: "dD${��d�N��t�\���P�" this does not look like base64! Are you sure this is how it is generated?

Comment: @Uzer hash is generated like this `Crypto.createHmac('sha1', signKey).update(bytes).digest();`

Comment: Well thats how you make "hash", post base64 encoding it should not have any non-ascii charectors. Surely try the toString method on the buffer you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote one of the functions wrong, i should have base64 encoded instead of decoding it

```
const encode = Buffer.from(hash, 'base64');
```

to this

```
const encode = Buffer.from(hash).toString('base64').toString('utf-8');
```

Now its perfect and matches the string length and works perfectly.